# Magento 2 | add custom customer attribute to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, customer-attribute

I created a custom customer attribute and now want the customer to be able to edit in in checkout.

How can I do that?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. once you created the customer custom attributes in order to allow to edit in checkout you need to add in billing or shipping address form using layout processor
2. You can use the extension attributes for the same and then use that custom attributes value in local storage or in checkout session and set the data of that attributes whenever billing or shipping form submitted